# How do I loop through a JavaScript object but not act upon specific keys?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, javascript-objects

Lets say I have 3 JavaScript objects like this:

```
var obj_parent = {
    main: $("#parent_main_1"),
    tab: $("#parent_tab_1"),
    story: {
        main:$("#story_main"),
        tab: $("#story_tab")
    },
    recipe: {
        main: $("#recipe_main"),
        tab: $("#recipe_tab")
    },
    car: {
        main: $("#car_main"),
        tab: $("#car_tab")
    },
    animal: {
        main: $("#animal_main"),
        tab: $("#animal_tab")
    }
};
```

I would like to loop through this object to hide all of the "mains" of recipe, car, and animal objects. I would like to use a loop so if I needed to add another object, I wouldn't have to change the code. I am doing this to become more comfortable with objects. I know that if it was an array I could do this:

```
for ( var i = 3; i < obj_parent.length; i++) {
    obj_parent[i][0].hide();
}
```

Each of these objects will be different and the key words will not be the same so the next one could look like this:

```
var obj_parent2 = {
    main: $("#parent_main_1"),
    tab: $("#parent_tab_1"),
    earth: {
        main:$("#earth_main"),
        tab: $("#earth_tab")
    },
    moon: {
        main: $("#moon_main"),
        tab: $("#moon_tab")
    },
    computer: {
        main: $("#computer_main"),
        tab: $("#computer_tab")
    },
    building: {
        main: $("#building_main"),
        tab: $("#building_tab")
    }
};
```

I would like for it to be strictly javascript, not jQuery. I am trying to understand the language. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Reading about [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) shoud help.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the properties of an object you can use `for .. in` loop ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). Since you want the solution to work with any object, you should include some duck typing and defensive programming - you should check if the desired properties/functions exist.

You can type something like this:

```
for(var key in obj_parent){
    var prop = obj_parent[key];

    // Check if the prop is truty, if it has a property with name main 
    // and if this main sub-property has function hide to avoid uncaught errors.
    if(prop && prop.main && typeof(prop.main.hide) === 'function') {
        prop.main.hide();
    }
}
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qz74hoq8/2/)

Comment: I did this to accomplish my goal. The only thing was that I wanted the story_main to be displayed or which ever one would be in that position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning, then for...in is what you are looking for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

But, personally, I despise for loops of any type in non-utility code. As a reader of the program, I have to stop at each for loop and figure out why the author is looping. (To find something? To filter to a subset of results? To visit each and cause some action? To extract some data?).  Far better is to use underscorejs (http://underscorejs.org).  Each of those actions are explicit.  (_.find, _.filter, _.each, _.map, _.pluck, etc)

```js
_.each(obj_parent, function(key, value){  /* do something */ })
```

Comment: If OP wants pure javascript, they could just use `Object.keys(obj_parent).forEach(function(key){ /* do something */ });`.  And btw, code snippets only make sense if you have a complete html/js example.  Otherwise, it's just taking up space.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @victorbahtev I ended up doing [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qz74hoq8/4/)

```
function testing(obj){
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in obj){
        var prop = obj[key];
        if(prop && prop.main &&typeof(prop.main.hide) === 'function') {
            if (i !== 0) 
                prop.main.hide();
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

What I added to his code was the counter and then inside the if statement in the loop, I made it check the counter and skip the first one that popped up with a main property.